# Compute signed long max value in C using bit shift

Tags: c, bit-shift

Just started learning C yesterday and this is about to drive me crazy on the new year's day... Try to print the different int ranges using bit shift operations. Everything works fine apart from the signed long max/min value. Can't figure out why `(1 << 63) - 1` returns `-1`? But `(1 << 64) -1` for `unsigned long long` works fine...

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_range() {
    signed char scmax = (1 << 7) - 1;
    char c = scmax; // char means signed char!
    unsigned char uscmax = (1 << 8) - 1;
    char cmin = -(1 << 7);
    unsigned char ucmin = 0;
    printf("signed char max: %d = %d, unsigned char max: %d = %d\n", scmax, SCHAR_MAX, uscmax, UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("signed char min: %d = %d, unsigned char min: %d\n", cmin, CHAR_MIN, ucmin);

    // signed int
    int imax = (1 << 31) - 1; //(2 << 30) - 1;
    unsigned int uimax = (1 << 32) - 1;
    int imin = -(1 << 31);
    //NOTE: %d is for signed char/short/int, %u is for the unsigned formatter.
    printf("signed int max: %d = %d, unsigned int max: %u = %u\n", imax, INT_MAX, uimax, UINT_MAX);
    printf("signed int min: %d = %d, unsigned int min = %d\n", imin, INT_MIN, 0);

    long long lmax = (1 << 63) - 1L; // WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK???
    unsigned long long ulmax = (1 << 64) - 1;
    long long lmin = -(1 << 63); // NEITHER DOES THIS???
    printf("signed long max: %lld = %lld, unsigned long max: %llu = %llu\n", lmax, LLONG_MAX, ulmax, ULLONG_MAX);
    printf("signed long min: %lld = %lld, unsigned long min: %d\n", lmin, LLONG_MIN, 0);
}
```

Comment: Without going through your code, maybe you should try printing in hex. You can use `%x` and `%llx`. You should be getting `0x7FFFFFFF`

Comment: `long long lmax = (1 << 63) - 1L;` --> `long long lmax = (1ULL << 63) - 1;`

Comment: If `int` has not more than 64 bits, `1 << 63` invokes undefined behaviour. The same for `1L << 63`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is evaluated as `int` as both operands are `int`s. You need to make them `long long`s:

```
((1LL << 63) - 1)
(((long long)1 << 63) -1)
```

Additionally, many architectures will shift by at most the size of the type -1, so it is shifted by just 31 bits for 63, and by 0 for 32 or 64.

`(1<<64)-1)` works differently than expected: `(1<<64)` is `0` due to as explained in previous paragraph. `0-1` is `-1` which is converted to `long long`, which is still `-1LL` and converted to `unsigned long long` it results into max `unsigned long long` (due to 2-complement representation of `signed` and `unsigned` numbers in common architectures)

Comment: why does `unsigned long long ulmax = (1 << 64) - 1;` work?

Comment: Did you mean when `-1LL` converted to unsigned, it results into max `unsigned long long` since max long long is not the same as max unsigned long long.

Comment: Super! This is very helpful! One more question, why does `(1LL << 63) - 1` in Visual Studio results a warning: Warning C4307 '-': integral constant overflow?

Comment: `1LL << 63` invokes undefined behavior if `long long` has only 64 bits because of signed arithmetic overflow.  You must use `1ULL << 63`.

Comment: @stt106 : because 1LL<<63 is just beyond max value of long long.

Comment: Ok, final question for today:) how to remove the warning of: shift count negative or too big, undefined behaviour in `unsigned long long ulmax = (1ULL << 64) - 1;`? @chqrlie

Comment: `(1<<64)` invokes undefined behavior. It may yield `0` on some platforms, but you cannot rely on this.

Comment: @stt106: similarly `1ULL << 64` invokes undefined behavior unless type `long long` has more than 64 bit, which is quite rare.  Use `~0ULL` to get the maximum value of type `unsigned long long`.  You could also use `-1ULL`, but it is less obviously unsigned.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Remember that a programming language is a *specification*, written in English in some technical report. It is not a software. For [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)</sup>

A literal constant like `1` is not a `long`, but an `int`.

To code a literal constant `long` 1, you need to write `1L` (or you might code `(long)1`....). To code a literal constant `unsigned long long` 1, you should write `1ULL` (or code `(unsigned long long)1` which is a constant expression).

A literal constant number fits the "smallest" integral type large enough to represent it. So `1` is an `int`, and on a 64 bit computer (actually, implementation of C like my Linux/x86-64 one) `10000000000` (that is 10<sup>10</sup>) is a `long` (because it does not fit in an `int`), since on such computers `int`-s have 32 bits and `long`-s have 64 bits.

<sup>Notice that the size or range of `int` is not precisely defined by the C99 or C11 standard, and could vary from one implementation to another. You may want to include the [`<stdint.h>` standard header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) and use types like `int32_t` ...</sup>

So `1 << 63`  is an `(int)1`  left shifted by 63 bits (since left operand is an `int` the shift is operating on `int`-s). On my Linux/x86-64, an `int` has only 32 bits, so that operation is an [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should be very scared of undefined behavior, see references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). And the sad thing is that occasionally, undefined behavior might happen to work like you desired it (but it still remains UB).

Another way of looking at your code is to be concerned about [software portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability).

---

BTW, take the habit to compile with all warnings & debug info, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Sometimes, the compiler is clever enough to warn you in such cases. Then, improve your code to remove all warnings. Later, use the debugger (`gdb`) to run your code step by step and understand (by querying the program's state in the debugger) what is happening.

---

In your code you have:

> ```
>      char c = scmax; // char means signed char!
> ```

Sadly, it is much more tricky. You have several variants or dialects of C. In some variants, a `char` is signed, in others, a `char` is unsigned. What variant you have is implementation specific (the compiler writer chooses the easiest to implement on some target architecture). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) see [C dialect options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) like `-fsigned-char` and  `-funsigned-char` (which you should almost never use, and when you do use them, be *very* careful of the consequences; you may need to recompile your entire C standard library).

Comment: Casting an `int` constant to `long long` is not a good idea. That's what the suffixes are for. But OP seems to want fixed-width types, so `UINT64_C(1)` would be the correct form. Also `long` is not guaranteed to be 64 bits on 64 bit architectures, this is a matter of the ABI, see Windows, which is IL32LLP64.

Comment: why does `unsigned long long ulmax = (1 << 64) - 1;` work?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the part about char can be signed or unsigned; I am aware of this and I am using Microsoft C/C++ compiler which treats char as signed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes undefined behavior on multiple counts:

- left shifting `1`, an `int` value, by more than the number of bits in the type minus one invokes undefined behavior ;
- left shifting a signed integer by any amount such that the resulting value exceeds the range of the type invokes undefined behavior, like all other signed arithmetic overflows.

Computing these maximum values with shifts is inconvenient.  If you can assume 2s complement and no padding bits, you can use the bitwise complement to get the maximum unsigned value and shift it once to the right to get the maximum signed value, then negate it and subtract one to get the minimum signed value.

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // char
    unsigned char ucmin = 0;
    unsigned char ucmax = ~ucmin;
    signed char scmax = ucmax >> 1;
    signed char scmin = -scmax - 1;
    char cmax = ((char)(-1)) < 0 ? scmax : ucmax;
    char cmin = ((char)(-1)) < 0 ? scmin : ucmin;
    printf("signed char min: %d = %d, signed char max: %d = %d\n",
           scmin, SCHAR_MIN, scmax, SCHAR_MAX);
    printf("unsigned char min: %d, unsigned char max: %u = %u\n",
           ucmin, ucmax, UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("char min: %d = %d, char max: %d = %d\n",
           cmin, CHAR_MIN, cmax, CHAR_MAX);

    // short
    unsigned short usmin = 0;
    unsigned short usmax = ~usmin;
    signed short smax = usmax >> 1;
    signed short smin = -smax - 1;
    printf("short min: %d = %d, short max: %d = %d\n",
           smin, SHRT_MIN, smax, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("unsigned short min: %d, unsigned sort max: %u = %u\n",
           usmin, usmax, USHRT_MAX);

    // int
    unsigned int umin = 0;
    unsigned int umax = ~umin;
    signed int imax = umax >> 1;
    signed int imin = -imax - 1;
    printf("int min: %d = %d, int max: %d = %d\n",
           imin, INT_MIN, imax, INT_MAX);
    printf("unsigned int min: %u, unsigned int max: %u = %u\n",
           umin, umax, UINT_MAX);

    // long int
    unsigned long ulmin = 0;
    unsigned long ulmax = ~ulmin;
    signed long lmax = ulmax >> 1;
    signed long lmin = -lmax - 1;
    printf("long int min: %ld = %ld, long int max: %ld = %ld\n",
           lmin, LONG_MIN, lmax, LONG_MAX);
    printf("unsigned long int min: %lu, unsigned long int max: %lu = %lu\n",
           ulmin, ulmax, ULONG_MAX);

    // long long int
    unsigned long long ullmin = 0;
    unsigned long long ullmax = ~ullmin;
    signed long long llmax = ullmax >> 1;
    signed long long llmin = -llmax - 1;
    printf("long long int min: %lld = %lld, long long int max: %lld = %lld\n",
           llmin, LLONG_MIN, llmax, LLONG_MAX);
    printf("unsigned long long int min: %llu, unsigned long long int max: %llu = %llu\n",
           ullmin, ullmax, ULLONG_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't know all these low level bit manipulations? If I can accept more than one answer, I would accept this one too as it's just awesome to see how things can be done properly; especially in a way not only in C but in other higher level languages like C# too.

Comment: @stt106: the bitwise complement operator `~` inverts all bits in its operand.  You can avoid it by using the subtraction: `unsigned char ucmax = ucmin - 1;`

Answer (score 1):

`(1LL << 63) - 1LL` should work, but if you are compiling with flags that detect integer overflow (like `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined`), it will give an error. In this case it is better to do:

```
((1LL << 62) - 1) | (1LL << 62)
```

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
long long lmax = (1 << 63) - 1L; // WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK???
```

does not work because a number is an `int` unless it is declared otherwise.

AN `int` is (usually) 32 bits
(your compiler should have told you about this with the message:

```
warning: integer overflow in exression [-Woverflow]
```

Similarly for the other expression that your having a problem with.

The fact that your compiler did not tell you about this problem means that your compiling without the warnings enabled.

for `gcc`, at a minimum use:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

I also find these parameters to be very useful:

```
-Wconversion -std=gnu99
```

Comment: Is using Microsoft c/c++ compiler really uncommon? Seems that everyone assumes gcc is being used whenever c/c++ is involved:)

Comment: @stt106,   actually using Visual C is very common (although it is way way behind the C standard)

Comment: I thought they updated the compiler with the latest release of VS2015?